# Pushforward of pullback of an etale sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, etale-cohomology

I hope this question is not too elementary, but I'm a bit lost :

Let $S$ be a finite set of closed points of $\mathbb{P^1_{C}}$ and $j : U \longrightarrow \mathbb{P^1_{C}}$ be the inclusion of the complement. I have an etale $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$-sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $\mathbb{P^1_{C}}$ such that $j^{*} \mathcal{F}$ is locally constant (hence corresponds to some $\ell$-adic representation $V$ of $\pi_{1,et}(U)$), and I would like to understand the fiber of $j_{*}j^{*} \mathcal{F}$ over a point $s \in S$. Is there a description of this fiber in term of the monodromy representation $V$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is just the invariants under the inertia group corresponding to the point. The reason is that the stalk of $j_*\mathcal{G}$ can be computed as global sections of $\mathcal{G}$ over $\text{Spec}(K^{sh})$ where $K^{sh}$ is the fraction field of the strictly henselian local ring $O_{\mathbf{P}^1, s}^{sh}$ at $s$, see [Theorem Tag 03Q9](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03Q9). To be sure, I am using that $s$ is not contained in $U$. Finally, you observe that the absolute Galois group of $K^{sh}$ is the inertia group and use [Lemma Tag 04JM](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04JM).

Comment: Thanks ! That's exactly what I was looking for.