# Stalk of pushforward sheaf on affine line

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

I have trouble understanding example 8.5.b) in Milne's Lectures on Etale Cohomology : let $X$ be the affine line over an algebraically closed field, $U=X-\{ 0 \}$ and let $j$ be the inclusion $U\to X$. Let $\mathcal{F} $ be a locally constant sheaf on $U$ corresponding to a $\pi_1(U,\bar{u})$-module $F$ where $\bar{u}$ is a geoemtric point of $U$. Then the geometric fibre $(j_*\mathcal{F})_0$ is $F^{\pi_1(U, \bar{u})}$.

I do understand the analogous example 8.5.a) in classical topology : if an open subset contains 0, then the sections of $\mathcal{F}$ on this subset are invariant under the action of the generator (loop around 0) of the fundamental group, and every term in the colimit defining the stalk is the same. But I don't see how this works in the etale setting.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this fibre is $F^{I_{\bar 0}}$ where $I_{\bar 0}$ is the inertia group at $\bar 0$ (see the following post : [Pushforward of pullback of an etale sheaf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763683/pushforward-of-pullback-of-an-etale-sheaf)), which happens to be $F^{\pi_1(U,\bar u)}$ here. Consider an etale cover $V\to U$ which trivializes $\mathcal{F}$. The action of $\pi_1(U,\bar u)$ on $F$ factors through $\mathrm{Aut}(V|U)$. Since $U=\mathbb{G}_m$, this cover is $\mathbb{G}_m\to\mathbb{G}_m, x\mapsto x^n$ for some integer $n$, and all its automorphisms fix the point $0\in V$ above $0\in U$ : they are all elements of the inertia group $I_0$ of $V\to U$. So $(j_\star\mathcal{F})_{
\bar 0}=F^{I_{\bar 0}}$ is indeed equal to $F^{\pi_1(U,\bar u)}$.